# Confusion about vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

I was reading a slide from a course on principle component analysis, and the notation caused me some confusion.
There is a data matrix X which is of dimension (n, d). So, the matrix has n rows, each of these row vectors represents a single data point, and d columns, each indicates a feature. However, later the author uses the notation $x_i (1 \leq i \leq n)$. This $x_i$ vector represents apparently a single data point too, but it's a column vector from the context.
So what I want to know is that is this a convention that the lower case x always indicates a column vector, despite the fact that it actually a row vector when it's part of matrix upper case X?

Edit: corrected some typos

Comment: In my humble opinion, it depends on context. In general, if you have a matrix $A$ of size $n\times m$, then to indicate a column vector you can write $A_{*j}$ and to indicate a row vector you can write $A_{i*}$, but in any other case, it depends on the area of math you're working on and even on the author. If you are not sure, just look at the indexes or wait to see how the vector is being used. However it may be, even if there's a typo, at the end it has to make sense.

Comment: There is absolutely no consistent convention. Computer graphics people work with row vectors; most others typically consider vectors to be column vectors. With a matrix $A$, some of us write $A_i$ for the $i$th row vector and $a_j$ for the $j$th column vector, but this is *far* from universal.

Comment: OK, got it, thank you guys very much!